# Adding new Branch rule for referral reward after 2 days after referred has installed app

Tags: branch.io

Planning to start implementing Branch dynamic link generation and referrals in my android app, but I have a specific use case that I would want to implement in coming days.

Because a user could install the app via the referred dynamic link but could also uninstall the paid app within first 48 hours, I would like to credit the user with referral reward only after 48 hour window, so that users don't take undue credits without actually keeping the app installed.

Is this possible using Branch dynamic links and Referrals system?

Answer (score 0):

Referrals are based on a session, not a device. If a user closes and opens the app before triggering the referral rule, then the referral points will not be delivered. You could achieve this by a little effort. You could set up a [webhook](https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/ua-webhooks/#search) and record the timestamp of when the referral event occurs and use the [reward API](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#referral-reward) to give the referring user a reward after the two days. If you have any further questions, feel free to reach out to integrations@branch.io.